# Cloudflare API: How many URL's can be purged from the cache from a single API call?

Tags: cloudflare

The Cloudflare API opens up the functionality to programmatically purge cached files.

The documentation on clearing files from the cache by URL is [well documented](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url) however there doesn't appear to be any information on the internet detailing how many individual URL's can be purged in a single API call.

So the question is, how many individual files can be purged from the cache on a single API call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that at this time, the maximum number of URL's per API call is 30.

If you need to purge more than 30 URL's then you can split the list of URL's into chunks of 30 and send them in batches.

Comment: can you also mention the source link, where you read that ?

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan closest I can find is in the new [zone purge](https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/zone-purge#purge-cached-content-by-tag-host-or-prefix) documentation where it states "You may purge up to 30 tags, hosts, or prefixes in one API call", I assume the same limit applies to the no longer fully documented URL purging.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid yes its 30 urls per API call